# Combine two files based in a common string

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to combine two files based on a matching string between the two files. in File1 the string is found in column 4 and in File2 the string is found between the symbols ":" and "-"

File1:

```
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   157784  157887  66.91   -       .       ID=RF00026.1;Name=RF00026;Alias=U6;Note=AL627309.15/147374-147271
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564813  564881  36.11   +       .       ID=RF00005.1;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43445-43513
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564879  564950  32.30   -       .       ID=RF00005.2;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43582-43511
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564952  565019  28.17   +       .       ID=RF00005.3;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43584-43651
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566062  566129  31.36   +       .       ID=RF00005.4;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44694-44761
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566137  566205  30.82   -       .       ID=RF00005.5;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44837-44769
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566207  566279  35.81   -       .       ID=RF00005.6;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44911-44839
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566311  566376  26.05   -       .       ID=RF00005.7;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/45008-44943
```

File2:

```
chr1:157783-157887      aaaaatatggaatgcttcacaaatttgcatgtcattctttcacagaggccgtgccaatctctctattgttccaacttaagtatgtgtgctactgaggcaagcaT
chr1:564812-564881      AGAAATATGTCTGATAAAAGAGTTACTTTGATAGAGTAAATAATAGGAGTTTAAATCCCCTTATTTcta
chr1:564878-564950      ctaggactatgagaatcgaacccatccctgagaatccaaaattctccgtgccacctatcacaccccatccta
chr1:564951-565019      AGTAAGGTCAGCTAAATAAGCTATCGGGCCCATACCCCGAAAATGTTGGTTATATCCTTCCCGTACTA
chr1:566061-566129      AGAAATTTAGGTTAAATACAGACCAAGAGCCTTCAAAGCCCTCAGTAAGTTGCAATACTTAATTTCTG
chr1:566136-566205      TAAGGACTGCAAAACCCCACTCTGCATCAACTGAACGCAAATCAGCCACTTTAATTAAGCTAAGCCCTT
chr1:566206-566279      CTAGACCAATGGGACTTAAACCCACAAACACTTAGTTAACAGCTAAGCACCCTAATCAACTGGCTTCAATCTA
chr1:566310-566376      AAGCCCCGGCAGGTTTGAAGCTGCTTCTTCGAATTTGCAATTCAATATGAAAATCACCTCAGAGCT
chr1:566376-566441      GGTAAAAAGAGGCTTAACCCCTGTCTTTAGATTTACAGTCCAATGCTTCACTCAGCCATTTTACC
chr1:568068-568136      AAGATATTAGAAAAACCATTTCATAACTTTGTCAAAGTTAAATTATAGGCTAAATCCTATATATCTTA
chr1:568843-568913      CACTGTAAAGCTAACTTAGCATTAACCTTTTAAGTTAAAGATTAAGAGAACCAACACCTCTTTACAGTGA
```

Output:

The output should contain all the columns from both files.

```
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   157784  157887  66.91   -       .       ID=RF00026.1;Name=RF00026;Alias=U6;Note=AL627309.15/147374-147271 chr1:157783-157887      aaaaatatggaatgcttcacaaatttgcatgtcattctttcacagaggccgtgccaatctctctattgttccaacttaagtatgtgtgctactgaggcaagcaT
....
....
```

I wrote this code to a  similar but not identical problem before:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw| input.log input1.log |; #you can give here path of files, or use @ARGV if you wish to pass files from command line 
my %data;

foreach my $filename (@files)
{
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open $filename for reading: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>)
    {
        chomp $line;
        my ($col1, $col2) = split /\s+/, $line;
        push @{ $data{$col1} }, $col2; #create an hash of array
    }
}
foreach my $col1 (sort keys %data)
{
    print join("\t", $col1, @{ $data{$col1} }), "\n";    
}
```

Comment: Have you started working on the problem and got stuck?

Comment: What is stopping you from using your existing program? How is it different? Also, how large are the two files? Can they be held in memory or are we talking GBs of text files?

Comment: `157784` is in file1 (column4) but not in file2. How are you comparing? Your output have this value.

Comment: True, its an error in the example output.

Comment: So what do you expect us to help you with? There is no question in your question. Do you want to just have the program changed so it works for this file format, or have you tried doing that and couldn't figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will join the two files on the columns/data requested. It will only print lines if there's a match.

**EDIT**: Showing results with new sample data:

```
$ cat f1
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   157783  157887  66.91   -   0   ID=RF00026.1;Name=RF00026;Alias=U6;Note=AL627309.15/147374-147271
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564812  564881  36.11   +   0   ID=RF00005.1;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43445-43513
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564878  564950  32.3    -   0   ID=RF00005.2;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43582-43511
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564951  565019  28.17   +   0   ID=RF00005.3;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43584-43651
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566061  566129  31.36   +   0   ID=RF00005.4;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44694-44761
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566136  566205  30.82   -   0   ID=RF00005.5;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44837-44769
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566206  566279  35.81   -   0   ID=RF00005.6;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44911-44839
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566310  566376  26.05   -   0   ID=RF00005.7;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/45008-44943
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566376  566441  37.46   -   0   ID=RF00005.8;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/45073-45009
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   568068  568136  31.45   +   0   ID=RF00005.9;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/46701-46768

$ cat f2
chr1:157783-157887  aaaaatatggaatgcttcacaaatttgcatgtcattctttcacagaggccgtgccaatctctctattgttccaacttaagtatgtgtgctactgaggcaagcaT
chr1:564812-564881  AGAAATATGTCTGATAAAAGAGTTACTTTGATAGAGTAAATAATAGGAGTTTAAATCCCCTTATTTcta
chr1:564878-564950  ctaggactatgagaatcgaacccatccctgagaatccaaaattctccgtgccacctatcacaccccatccta
chr1:564951-565019  AGTAAGGTCAGCTAAATAAGCTATCGGGCCCATACCCCGAAAATGTTGGTTATATCCTTCCCGTACTA
chr1:566061-566129  AGAAATTTAGGTTAAATACAGACCAAGAGCCTTCAAAGCCCTCAGTAAGTTGCAATACTTAATTTCTG
chr1:566136-566205  TAAGGACTGCAAAACCCCACTCTGCATCAACTGAACGCAAATCAGCCACTTTAATTAAGCTAAGCCCTT
chr1:566206-566279  CTAGACCAATGGGACTTAAACCCACAAACACTTAGTTAACAGCTAAGCACCCTAATCAACTGGCTTCAATCTA
chr1:566310-566376  AAGCCCCGGCAGGTTTGAAGCTGCTTCTTCGAATTTGCAATTCAATATGAAAATCACCTCAGAGCT
chr1:566376-566441  GGTAAAAAGAGGCTTAACCCCTGTCTTTAGATTTACAGTCCAATGCTTCACTCAGCCATTTTACC
chr1:568068-568136  AAGATATTAGAAAAACCATTTCATAACTTTGTCAAAGTTAAATTATAGGCTAAATCCTATATATCTTA


$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="[\t :-]+"} NR==FNR {a[$4]=$0; next} $2 in a {print a[$2], $0}' f1 f2
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   157783  157887  66.91   -   0   ID=RF00026.1;Name=RF00026;Alias=U6;Note=AL627309.15/147374-147271 chr1:157783-157887  aaaaatatggaatgcttcacaaatttgcatgtcattctttcacagaggccgtgccaatctctctattgttccaacttaagtatgtgtgctactgaggcaagcaT
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564812  564881  36.11   +   0   ID=RF00005.1;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43445-43513 chr1:564812-564881  AGAAATATGTCTGATAAAAGAGTTACTTTGATAGAGTAAATAATAGGAGTTTAAATCCCCTTATTTcta
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564878  564950  32.3    -   0   ID=RF00005.2;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43582-43511 chr1:564878-564950  ctaggactatgagaatcgaacccatccctgagaatccaaaattctccgtgccacctatcacaccccatccta
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   564951  565019  28.17   +   0   ID=RF00005.3;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/43584-43651 chr1:564951-565019  AGTAAGGTCAGCTAAATAAGCTATCGGGCCCATACCCCGAAAATGTTGGTTATATCCTTCCCGTACTA
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566061  566129  31.36   +   0   ID=RF00005.4;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44694-44761 chr1:566061-566129  AGAAATTTAGGTTAAATACAGACCAAGAGCCTTCAAAGCCCTCAGTAAGTTGCAATACTTAATTTCTG
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566136  566205  30.82   -   0   ID=RF00005.5;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44837-44769 chr1:566136-566205  TAAGGACTGCAAAACCCCACTCTGCATCAACTGAACGCAAATCAGCCACTTTAATTAAGCTAAGCCCTT
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566206  566279  35.81   -   0   ID=RF00005.6;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/44911-44839 chr1:566206-566279  CTAGACCAATGGGACTTAAACCCACAAACACTTAGTTAACAGCTAAGCACCCTAATCAACTGGCTTCAATCTA
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566310  566376  26.05   -   0   ID=RF00005.7;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/45008-44943 chr1:566310-566376  AAGCCCCGGCAGGTTTGAAGCTGCTTCTTCGAATTTGCAATTCAATATGAAAATCACCTCAGAGCT
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   566376  566441  37.46   -   0   ID=RF00005.8;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/45073-45009 chr1:566376-566441  GGTAAAAAGAGGCTTAACCCCTGTCTTTAGATTTACAGTCCAATGCTTCACTCAGCCATTTTACC
chr1    Rfam    ncRNA   568068  568136  31.45   +   0   ID=RF00005.9;Name=RF00005;Alias=tRNA;Note=AC114498.2/46701-46768 chr1:568068-568136  AAGATATTAGAAAAACCATTTCATAACTTTGTCAAAGTTAAATTATAGGCTAAATCCTATATATCTTA
```

Comment: I've updated my answer using the new sample files.  Can you show the exact awk command you are using?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ :-]*"} NR==FNR {a[$4]=$0; next} $2 in a {print a[$2], $0}' rfam.csv rfamFastaTab.csv

Comment: Make sure you you have the files in the right order on the command line. `rfam.csv` should be the one with the match in column 4, `rfamFastaTab.csv` should be the one with the ATGC sequences. If it's the opposite, switch their order on the command line.

Comment: the order is corrent, dont know why its does not work

Comment: What does this output?  `awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ :-]*"} {print $4}' rfam.csv`. And this? `awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ :-]*"} {print $2}' rfamFastaTab.csv`

Comment: the first outputs numbers with a lot of blank lines

Comment: the second outputs lines with numbers without blank lines

Comment: The numbers we expect (e.g., "157783", "564951", etc.)?

Comment: Can you try replacing the `BEGIN` block with `BEGIN {FS="[\t :-]+"}` (the change is in the file separator)?